# Buffering while popen working

Tags: c, popen

I'm using the following command to get a constant output of a two digit value:

```
pipe = popen("hcidump -a | egrep --line-buffered 'RSSI|bdaddr' | grep -A1 --line-buffered --no-group-separator 'bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66' | grep -Po --line-buffered 'RSSI:\\s+\\K.*'", "r");
```

I want to buffer that, so I can transform it into a integer value and work with it. but I'm not sure how to achieve that. As long as I have popen running my C-programm will not go on. I checked it with strace and he will read the value in popen and will not termit.

the rest of the code looks like that:

```
if (pipe) 
    {
        printf("entered pipe-if");

        while(!feof(pipe)) 
        {
            if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL){}
        }   
        pclose(pipe);
        printf("pclose");
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
    }
```

The idea behind it is that I want to use the Data to calculate a distnace in "realtime". A possibility would be that I could tell popen to end the process after x seconds, then use the buffered data and then start the process from the beginning.

Thanks for help and advice.

Comment: why do you think there's going to be an EOF?

Comment: I know there is no EOF, I was trying some things out and that remained. my mistake to put it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using popen to open the pipe you should work with the file descriptor rather than the FILE pointer.  You can then turn the file to non-blocking and process the data as it comes in.

```
int fd = fileno(pipe);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Then you can read data from the pipe using

```
bytes = read(fd, buf, bufsize);
```

If bytes is greater than 0, then you have some more data to process.  If bytes is -1 and errno is EAGAIN, then there's nothing in the pipe.  Anything else you're done.  You'll have to deal with the data however it comes in (ie you don't get fgets() nicely doing things per-line)

Comment: But doesn't that leave me with the same problem? as I first use popen with a never ending output, i will never come to the point of fileno, fcntl and read?

Comment: By making the file descriptor non-blocking you have control back in your program even if there is no output, so you can implement your own timeout if necessary.  While I can't say I completely understand the use case, it looks to me like you'd be better off opening the pipe and processing data  when you see new data (ie at each return of fgets() or read() in my version), rather than after you've closed the pipe.

Comment: Use case is that i want to read RSSI-values from an iBeacon to know if it is near, medium or far away from my device. And depending on the value i need to give further instructions. That's why I need to read constantly for the values and react to them. It doesn't need to be realtime, but frequently. Means i can collect some data (like a second or two) and then process further. I will try your approach later.