# Create pipe but read its stdout later

Tags: c, linux, pipe, stdout

I create pipe for reading (in C using `popen`) and read its output using fgets - and it works well.

But now I need two improvements, and not sure how to proceed - most answers are relatively old, maybe problem is solved but I can not find it.

So:

1. make pipe reading asynchronous. I can do it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38182355) suggestion. Now I should be able to do something else while waiting for data from the pipe or use timeout timer to close it if it hangs.
2. read pipe later - open pipe, then do some task, and then return to reading pipe after some time - having piped applications doing their work and performing output to the pipe - so that I come to reading pipe with its work already on the way, not just started. This requires some buffer, but there seems [no much control over it](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/). It is not clear what buffer size is, and how pipe will behave if not being read on various implementations.

The obvious way to proceed is to create a thread for piping, and it will perform gathering of output in parallel to main task. But is there a better, less complicated way? Thanks.

Comment: Adding details about the program you are implementing and the command you run might help to propose a solution. (If you are running standard tools, the command would be sufficient, otherwise also add details about the purpose and behavior of the called program.) With `popen` and `fgets` you automatically have a pipe buffer and input buffering. `popen` does not give you much control, but simplicity and maybe resulting problems. You would have more flexibility (and more complicated code) with `pipe`, `fork`, `exec*`. An alternative to using threads might be `select` with non-blocking I/O.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the expected time interval between the non-blocking reads from the pipe from your process, and on the particular program (shell command) started by `popen`.

If the interval is too long so that the pipe buffer gets full, the default behaviour of most programs on the writing end of the pipe is to block. While they are blocked on writing to the pipe, they probably won't do any other stuff either, unless they are multi-threaded.

You can experiment with a child process that sends a lot of output in a short amount of time, say `cat` on a big file.

The [`pipe(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) manual page tells us this:

> Pipe capacity
>
> A pipe has a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a
> write(2) will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK
> flag is set (see below).  Different implementations have
> different limits for the pipe capacity.  Applications should not
> rely on a particular capacity: an application should be designed
> so that a reading process consumes data as soon as it is
> available, so that a writing process does not remain blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options.

1. Creating a thread that reads from the pipe and puts the result in a (dynamically growing if necessary) buffer that you have control over.
2. Use `select`(-like) waiting for events on different file descriptors. POSIX also supports `poll` and Linux additionally supports `epoll`.